# Google Chat Bot: Returning a threaded reply in onMessage() creates a new message in Space

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-chat

We've been trying to update our ChatBots to use threaded replies, but we're running into issues, specifically when responding to a brand new message in the Space. For example, if a user says:

```
@TheChatBot help!
```

We want the bot to create a threaded reply to that message. Instead, it creates a new message at the top level of the space.

Interestingly, if we mention the bot from WITHIN a thread, it works correctly.

We tried many combinations of `message.thread` values (e.g. `{ threadKey: ...}` , `{name: ...}`) and none of the combinations worked for the message outside of a thread.

Here's a snippet of the ChatBot gs code:

```
function onMessage(event) {
...
  var message = event.message;
  var threadName = message.thread ? message.thread.name : null;
...
  return {
    text: ...,
    threadReply: true,
    thread: {
      name: threadName
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My investigation revealed that Google Chat currently restricts response placement to the top-level space name, even though individual thread names *(messages where the chatbot was mentioned)* are readily available within the `onMessage` response *(**e.g.**,`spaces/SPACE_ID/threads/THREAD_ID`)*.

---

### Current Behavior

Official documentation on Processing or Responding to Interaction Events confirms that Chat bots are currently limited to **"Insert content to space"** *(see image below)* for their replies, suggesting this behavior is intentional:

[image]

### What I Have Tried

I attempted to formulate a workaround following the guide [`spaces.message.create`](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/auth/service-accounts#prerequisites). In this process, I intended for the chatbot to create a message on the thread where it has been mentioned, with use of the **thread name**. However, it appears there is a limitation in the **Chat API**. Specifically, one of the required parameters is a top-level Space name instead of a thread name.

### Last Resort

Having said that, I would recommend that you consider submitting a feature idea on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker#public_users). I believe this would be an ideal request for the chatbot, given its use cases such as the primary goal mentioned in your post.